# Task Parallel Library - I don't understand what I'm doing wrong

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

This is a two part question. 
I have a class that gets all processes asynchronously and polls them for CPU usage. Yesterday I had a bug with it and it was solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909776/get-all-processes-in-parallel). 
The first part of the question is why the solution helped. I didn't understand the explanation. 
The second part of the question is that I still get an `"Object reference not set to an instance of object"` exception occasionally when I try to print the result at the end of the process. This is because `item.Key` is indeed null. I don't understand why that is because I put a breakpoint checking for `(process == null)` and it was never hit. What am I doing wrong? 
Code is below.

```
class ProcessCpuUsageGetter
    {
        private IDictionary<Process, int> _usage;

        public IDictionary<Process, int> Usage { get { return _usage; } }

        public ProcessCpuUsageGetter()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
                int processCount = processes.Count();
                Task[] tasks = new Task[processCount];

                _usage = new Dictionary<Process, int>();
                for (int i = 0; i < processCount; i++)
                {
                    var localI = i;
                    var localProcess = processes[localI];
                    tasks[localI] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoWork(localProcess));
                }
                Task.WaitAll(tasks);

                foreach (var item in Usage)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}%", item.Key.ProcessName, item.Value);
                }                
            }
        }

        private void DoWork(object o)
        {
            Process process = (Process)o;
            PerformanceCounter pc = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", process.ProcessName, true);
            pc.NextValue();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            int cpuPercent = (int)pc.NextValue() / Environment.ProcessorCount;
            if (process == null)
            {
                var x = 5;
            }
            if (_usage == null)
            {
                var t = 6;
            }
            _usage.Add(process, cpuPercent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: "first part of the question is why the solution helped" - then please ask it in a comment under that question/answer.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why does `DoWork` take an `object` argument only to cast it into a `Process` right away?

Comment: @Henk - already asked it under the comments, but got no reply.

Comment: @Matti - leftover code, I should've changed it.

Comment: use the words (capture) to look it up. It's a very common mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line

```
 _usage.Add(process, cpuPercent);
```

is accessing a not-threadsafe collection from a thread.

Use a `ConcurrentDictionary<K,V>` instead of the normal dictionary.

The 'null reference' error is just a random symptom, you could get other errors too.